# How many promises can Perl 6 keep?

Tags: multithreading, promise, raku

That's a bit of a glib title, but in playing around with [Promises](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Promise) I wanted to see how far I could stretch the idea. In this program, I make it so I can specify how many promises I want to make.

- The default value in the thread scheduler is 16 threads ([rakudo/ThreadPoolScheduler.pm](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/3ff01249f1e14658600511f95f36dd88dbd63837/src/core/ThreadPoolScheduler.pm))
- If I specify more than that number, the program hangs but I don't get a warning (say, like "Too many threads").
- If I set RAKUDO_MAX_THREADS, I can stop the program hanging but eventually there is too much thread competition to run.

I have two questions, really.

- How would a program know how many more threads it can make? That's slightly more than the number of promises, for what that's worth.
- How would I know how many threads I should allow, even if I can make more?

This is Rakudo 2017.01 on my puny Macbook Air with 4 cores:

```
my $threads = @*ARGS[0] // %*ENV<RAKUDO_MAX_THREADS> // 1;
put "There are $threads threads";

my $channel = Channel.new;

# start some promises
my @promises;
for 1 .. $threads {
    @promises.push: start {
        react {
            whenever $channel -> $i {
                say "Thread {$*THREAD.id} got $i";
                }
            }
        }
    }
put "Done making threads";

for ^100 { $channel.send( $_ ) }
put "Done sending";

$channel.close;

await |@promises;

put "Done!";
```

Comment: Some of this may change with the next version of Perl, 6.d: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/1004

Comment: This isn't really about promises but about threads…

Comment: As a consumer, I don't care if it's about threads as long as the things I try to do actually work. If promises were implemented in some other way I'd have the same question.

Answer (score 11):

This isn't actually about `Promise` per se, but rather about the thread pool scheduler. A `Promise` itself is just a synchronization construct. The `start` construct actually does two things:

1. Ensures a fresh `$_`, `$/`, and `$!` inside of the block
2. Calls `Promise.start` with that block

And `Promise.start` also does two things:

1. Creates and returns a `Promise`
2. Schedules the code in the block to be run on the thread pool, and arranges that successful completion keeps the `Promise` and an exception breaks the `Promise`.

It's not only possible, but also relatively common, to have `Promise` objects that aren't backed by code on the thread pool. `Promise.in`, `Promise.anyof` and `Promise.allof` factories don't immediately schedule anything, and there are all kinds of uses of a `Promise` that involve doing `Promise.new` and then calling `keep` or `break` later on. So I can easily create and `await` on 1000 `Promise`s:

```
my @p = Promise.new xx 1000;
start { sleep 1; .keep for @p };
await @p;
say 'done' # completes, no trouble
```

Similarly, a `Promise` is not the only thing that can schedule code on the `ThreadPoolScheduler`. The many things that return `Supply` (like intervals, file watching, asynchronous sockets, asynchronous processes) all schedule their callbacks there too. It's possible to throw code there fire-and-forget style by doing `$*SCHEDULER.cue: { ... }` (though often you care about the result, or any errors, so it's not especially common).

The current Perl 6 thread pool scheduler has a configurable but enforced upper limit, which defaults to 16 threads. If you create a situation where all 16 are occupied but unable to make progress, and the only thing that can make progress is stuck in the work queue, then deadlock will occur. This is nothing unique to Perl 6 thread pool; any bounded pool will be vulnerable to this (and any unbounded pool will be vulnerable to using up all resources and getting the process killed :-)).

As mentioned in another post, Perl 6.d will make `await` and `react` non-blocking constructs; this has always been the plan, but there was insufficient development resources to realize it in time for Perl 6.c. The `use v6.d.PREVIEW` pragma provides early access to this feature. (Also, fair warning, it's a work in progress.) The upshot of this is that an `await` or `react` on a thread owned by the thread pool will pause the execution of the scheduled code (for those curious, by taking a continuation) and and allow the thread to get on with further work. The resumption of the code will be scheduled when the awaited thing completes, or the `react` block gets `done`. Note that this means you can be on a different OS thread before and after the `await` or `react` in 6.d. (Most Perl 6 users will not need to care about this. It's mostly relevant for those writing bindings to C libraries, or doing over systems-y stuff. And a good C library binding will make it so users of the binding don't have to care.)

The upcoming 6.d change doesn't eliminate the possibility of exhausting the thread pool, but it will mean a bunch of ways that you can do in 6.c will no longer be of concern (of note, writing recursive conquer/divide things that `await` the results of the divided parts, or having thousands of active react blocks launched with `start react { ... }`).

Looking forward, the thread pool scheduler itself will also become smarter. What follows is speculation, though given I'll likely be the one implementing the changes it's probably the best speculation on offer. :-) The thread pool will start following the progress being made, and use it to dynamically tune the pool size. This will include noticing that no progress is being made and, combined with the observation that the work queues contain items, adding threads to try and resolve the deadlock - at the cost of memory overhead of added threads. Today the thread pool conservatively tends to spawn up to its maximum size anyway, even if this is not a particularly optimal choice; most likely some kind of hill-climbing algorithm will be used to try and settle on an optimal number instead. Once that happens, the default max_threads can be raised substantially, so that more programs will - at the cost of a bunch of memory overhead - be able to complete, but most will run with just a handful of threads.

Answer (score 6):

Quick fix, add `use v6.d.PREVIEW;` on the first line.
This fixes a number of thread exhaustion issues.

I added a few other changes like `$*SCHEDULER.max_threads`, and adding the Promise “id” so that it is easy to see that the Thread id doesn't necessarily correlate with a given Promise.

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.d.PREVIEW; # <--

my $threads = @*ARGS[0] // $*SCHEDULER.max_threads;
put "There are $threads threads";

my $channel = Channel.new;

# start some promises
my @promises;
for 1 .. $threads {
    @promises.push: start {
        react {
            whenever $channel -> $i {
                say "Thread $*THREAD.id() ($_) got $i";
            }
        }
    }
}
put "Done making threads";

for ^100 { $channel.send( $_ ) }
put "Done sending";

$channel.close;

await @promises;

put "Done!";
```

```
There are 16 threads
Done making threads
Thread 4 (14) got 0
Thread 4 (14) got 1
Thread 8 (8) got 3
Thread 10 (6) got 4
Thread 6 (1) got 5
Thread 16 (5) got 2
Thread 3 (16) got 7
Thread 7 (8) got 8
Thread 7 (9) got 9
Thread 5 (3) got 6
Thread 3 (6) got 10
Thread 11 (2) got 11
Thread 14 (5) got 12
Thread 4 (16) got 13
Thread 16 (15) got 14 # <<
Thread 13 (11) got 15
Thread 4 (15) got 16 # <<
Thread 4 (15) got 17 # <<
Thread 4 (15) got 18 # <<
Thread 11 (15) got 19 # <<
Thread 13 (15) got 20 # <<
Thread 3 (15) got 21 # <<
Thread 9 (13) got 22
Thread 18 (15) got 23 # <<
Thread 18 (15) got 24 # <<
Thread 8 (13) got 25
Thread 7 (15) got 26 # <<
Thread 3 (15) got 27 # <<
Thread 7 (15) got 28 # <<
Thread 8 (15) got 29 # <<
Thread 13 (13) got 30
Thread 14 (13) got 31
Thread 8 (13) got 32
Thread 6 (13) got 33
Thread 9 (15) got 34 # <<
Thread 13 (15) got 35 # <<
Thread 9 (15) got 36 # <<
Thread 16 (15) got 37 # <<
Thread 3 (15) got 38 # <<
Thread 18 (13) got 39
Thread 3 (15) got 40 # <<
Thread 7 (14) got 41
Thread 12 (15) got 42 # <<
Thread 15 (15) got 43 # <<
Thread 4 (1) got 44
Thread 11 (1) got 45
Thread 7 (15) got 46 # <<
Thread 8 (15) got 47 # <<
Thread 7 (15) got 48 # <<
Thread 17 (15) got 49 # <<
Thread 10 (10) got 50
Thread 10 (15) got 51 # <<
Thread 11 (14) got 52
Thread 6 (8) got 53
Thread 5 (13) got 54
Thread 11 (15) got 55 # <<
Thread 11 (13) got 56
Thread 3 (13) got 57
Thread 7 (13) got 58
Thread 16 (16) got 59
Thread 5 (15) got 60 # <<
Thread 5 (15) got 61 # <<
Thread 6 (15) got 62 # <<
Thread 5 (15) got 63 # <<
Thread 5 (15) got 64 # <<
Thread 17 (11) got 65
Thread 15 (15) got 66 # <<
Thread 17 (15) got 67 # <<
Thread 11 (13) got 68
Thread 10 (15) got 69 # <<
Thread 3 (15) got 70 # <<
Thread 11 (15) got 71 # <<
Thread 6 (15) got 72 # <<
Thread 16 (13) got 73
Thread 6 (13) got 74
Thread 17 (15) got 75 # <<
Thread 4 (13) got 76
Thread 8 (13) got 77
Thread 12 (15) got 78 # <<
Thread 6 (11) got 79
Thread 3 (15) got 80 # <<
Thread 11 (13) got 81
Thread 7 (13) got 82
Thread 4 (15) got 83 # <<
Thread 7 (15) got 84 # <<
Thread 7 (15) got 85 # <<
Thread 10 (15) got 86 # <<
Thread 7 (15) got 87 # <<
Thread 12 (13) got 88
Thread 3 (13) got 89
Thread 18 (13) got 90
Thread 6 (13) got 91
Thread 18 (13) got 92
Thread 15 (15) got 93 # <<
Thread 16 (15) got 94 # <<
Thread 12 (15) got 95 # <<
Thread 17 (15) got 96 # <<
Thread 11 (13) got 97
Thread 15 (16) got 98
Thread 18 (7) got 99
Done sending
Done!
```

Comment: where is the Promise "id" documented?

Comment: @briandfoy There is no such thing, hence the quote marks. I was referring to the number that was in `$_` because of the `for` loop.